# Issue with force:inputfield inside lightning:tabset/tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am having this particular issue with lightning components while using `force:inputfield` within `lightning:tabset`.

Here is my component code:

```
<aura:component controller="AutoTableController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="opp" default=" { sobjectType : 'Opportunity'} " type="Opportunity" description="Pass the Opportunity which is to be edited" />
    <aura:attribute name="isEditEnabled" type="Boolean" description="If set to yes, will enable the edit node" />

    <lightning:tabset aura:id="tabset">
        <lightning:tab label="ACP">
            <aura:set attribute="body">
                <force:inputField aura:id="plan" value="{!v.opp.AccountId}" />
                <ui:outputText value="{!v.opp.Name}"></ui:outputText>
                <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Section Information</h3>
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

The `doinit` method fetched an opportunity record and does update the view as I am able to see the opportunity name but the `force:inputfield` is not rendered even though opportunity is linked to an account.

More Information:

1. I am fetching two fields from Apex Controller: Name, AccountId
2. The data json that is recived by controller method is `{"Name":"MS_No Territory","AccountId":"00136000003FIu6AAG","Id":"006360000049pUOAAY"}`
3. I am System Administrator
4. If I move the code out of `tab` component, it works perfectly.

I am using an attribute for Opportunity as `lightning:tabset` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm) says:

> This component creates its body during runtime. You won’t be able to
>   reference the component during initialization. You can set your
>   content using value binding with component attributes instead.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. i was just wondering, if you have solved this issue ?

Comment: @naruto-sfdc Sorry. I was not able to and moved to Jquery Tabs.